# Samsung A9 Pro - an error has occurred while updating the device software

Tags: samsung, updates, recovery-mode

I just purchased this phone from ebay and when I turned it on I get the following error:

[an error has occurred while updating the device software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhrnP.jpg)

Anybody know what's wrong with this phone?

Thanks.

Comment: Something scary:) I'd rather return the phone to seller or open Ebay case if he refuses. I highly doubt this thing is recoverable on your own.

Comment: It actually wasn't that bad. I just had to reinstall the device's firmware.